# how to delete only one clone of a game object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For example I have `coin1(clone)` and `coin1(clone)(clone)`. If I click `coin1(clone)(clone)` it will be destroyed. But in my case, when I click `coin1(clone)(clone)`, `coin1(Clone)` is deleted.

Codes I've been using

```
void NumberOfSelectedCoins()
{
    Debug.Log (BlueCoinScript.b);
    if(SelectedCoins.cntCoins%BlueCoinScript.b == 0)
    {

        for (int n=0;n<selectC.selectedNumCoins.Count; n++) 
        {
            Destroy(selectC.selectedNumCoins[n]);
            TotalSum.totalValue = 0;
            SelectedCoins.breakPointsCount++;
        }
        breakpointsText.text = SelectedCoins.breakPointsCount.ToString ();
        selectC.selectedNumCoins.Clear();
    }
}
```

And also if you have 1 game object and you cloned it so that you can have 3 same game objects, how can you identify that when you clicked that game object, that game object is clone1 or clone2 or clone3?

Answer (score 0):

You can for example identify GameObject instances by `Object.GetInstanceID()` or by `Object.name`. In the latter case though you have to take care that the object you search for is named and that this name is unique.

Further reference is found [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.html).